# How to get DBpedia content on HTTPS?

Tags: angular, api, http, https, dbpedia

Currently, I am using DBpedia to get information about Search Query in a Project but now we have migrated to HTTPS and now the contents of DBpedia is getting blocked as it is on HTTP.
Currently I am using this URL:`http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search/KeywordSearch?QueryString=`
and I am able to results from DBpedia but I want this on HTTPS. Changing `http` to `https` do not give results as I think they do not provide contents over https. What can I do? Any suggestion will be very helpful?